# Why is my UART2 not sending output on teraterm using embedded C on stm32f722ze?

Tags: stm32, embedded, arm, keil

Here is the code i have tried.

```
#include "uart.h"

void USART2_Init(void){
   
//enable clk access to uart
`RCC->APB1ENR |= (1<<17);
`
//enable clk access to port a
RCC->AHB1ENR |= (1<<0);
   
//enable pins for AF, pa2 n pa3
GPIOA->MODER &= ~0xFF00;
GPIOA->MODER |= 0x00A0;

//configure type of AF

GPIOA->AFR[0] &= ~0xFF00;
GPIOA->AFR[0] |= 0x7700;
   
//configure uart
USART2->BRR = 0x0683;
USART2->CR1 = 0x000C;
USART2->CR2 = 0x000; // stop bits 1
USART2->CR3 = 0x000;
USART2->CR1 |= (1<<0);
   
}

int USART2_write(int ch){
   while (!(USART2->ISR & 0x0080)){}
       USART2->TDR = (ch & 0xFF);
   return ch;
}

int USART2_read(void){
while (!(USART2->ISR & 0x0020)){}
   return USART2->RDR;
   
}

struct __FILE{int handle; };
FILE __stdin = {0};
FILE __stdout = {1};
FILE __stderr = {2};

int fgetc(FILE *f){
   
int c;
c = USART2_read();

if (c=='\r'){
USART2_write(c);
c='\n';
}

USART2_write(c);
return c;
}

int fputc(int c, FILE *f){
return USART2_write(c);
}

int n;
char str[80];

void test_setup(void){

printf("please enter a number: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("the number entered is: %d\r\n", n);
printf("please type a character string: ");
gets(str);
printf("the character string entered is: ");
puts(str);
printf("\r\n");
}
```

I went through various related videos and posts, still I am not able to solve it. please help me to find the error.`

Comment: What have you tested? I’d suggest you start at the USART2_write function. If you can’t see evidence of the status changing, I’d suggest you start at the basics and double check what port pins you want the tx and rx on. It can get confusing it you look at the wrong ic package pin table. Configure the pins as gpio outputs and write test code to set them high and low. Measure the pins with an oscilloscope, multimeter or hookup a led and resistor. Have you connected the rx and tx the right way around? You’ve got 50% chance of getting it wrong. You can verify this with a led and resistor.